# Ruby on Rails - Check user active before login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I'm trying to check attribute `state` of model `user` before successful login (name & pass correct). Using sessions `sessions_controler`

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
end
```

Migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def change
        create_table :users do |t|
            t.string :name
            t.string :email
            t.string :password_digest
            t.integer :type
            t.integer :state

            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

My `session_controller` create action ( state = 0:inactive / 1: active)

```
def create
    user = User.find_by name: params[:session][:name].downcase

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]) && user.state == 1
        flash[:success] = "Login successed"
        log_in user
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Login failed"
        render :new
    end
end
```

Rails routes

```
get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
post "login" => "sessions#create"
```

But result of `user.state == 1` in `session_controller` always `false`. I am sure that user I used for checking have `state 1` in database.

Thanks everyone for helping

Comment: Are you sure there are no users with the same `name`?

Comment: Check `User.where(name: params[:session][:name].downcase).count`. If it is more than 1, fix your controller logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to add a comment, but I'd like to ask you whether you are using Devise?

If you are, you can add a filter to the controller:

`before_action :authenticate_user!` You can also specify which methods to apply to the filter

`before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if we leave the implementation of create in session_controller as devise provides. As you already making a find query to the user, lets make it in before_action in sessions_controller. It will fulfil your requirement to check state before checking user credentials.

*in sessions_controller*

```
before_action :authenticate_user_state, only: [:create]

private

def authenticate_user_state
  user = User.find_by name: params[:session][:name].downcase

  redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: 'Login Failed'
end
```

I hope that helps you.